# Can't close editor part with big zest graph

Tags: eclipse, graph, editor, zest

I built an editor part in eclipse to visualize a Zest graph. My problem: if I try to close an editor part which contains a big graph (~6000 nodes, 9000 edges), eclipse can't handle the closing operation and hangs up.

Any ideas to solve the problem or debug it?

I think the problem is to dispose the graph object, but I have not idea to solve it.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was the method "org.eclipse.gef4.zest.layouts.algorithms.TreeLayoutObserver.TreeNode.isAncestorO‌​f(TreeNode descendant)". I fixed it for me and I will report a bug (for bug id show in the comments). If someone needs a quick bug fix:

old version:

```
    public boolean isAncestorOf(TreeNode descendant) {
        while (descendant.depth > this.depth) {
            descendant = descendant.parent;
        }
        return descendant == this;
    }
```

new version:

```
    public boolean isAncestorOf(TreeNode descendant) {
        while (descendant.depth > this.depth) {
            if (descendant == descendant.parent) {
                return false;
            } else {
                descendant = descendant.parent;
            }
        }
        return descendant == this;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

To debug it, I'd try to look into the Eclipse log file (`workspace/.metadata/.log`) for clues on what happened. It might be some memory issue. If it sounds like that form the log file, you could try to alter your `eclipse.ini` config, in particular the `-XX:MaxPermSize`, `-Xms`, and `-Xmx` values (see http://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse.ini).

If the problem persists with reasonable memory values, it would be great if you could file a bug: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/enter_bug.cgi?product=GEF&component=Zest

Comment: There's no logged information about my problem and I don't think that it's a memory problem because in this case I should get some exceptions?

Comment: @Yannic I'd still try to set some larger memory settings and see what happens. You could also try a clean Eclipse setup, e.g. just the SDK + Zest. If it still hangs up I'd be very happy about a bug report with an SSCCE: http://sscce.org/

Comment: I made some simple examples with 7000 nodes and 10,000 edges. My results: closing one graph with 7000 nodes and 10,000 edges is no problem. Closing a Graph object with 10 subgraphs is a problem. Can you explain which methods are called when the user closes an editor in which a Graph object is contained? I tried to build a new class "ExtendedGraph" which extends the Graph class and overrides the dispose method to log the calls of this method. But there is no call...

Comment: @Yannic Interesting, so it's a subgraph issue - could you file a bug with a sample snippet to reproduce this at https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/enter_bug.cgi?product=GEF&component=Zest

Comment: I checked out the repository and debugged the code. The exact problem is the method: org.eclipse.gef4.zest.layouts.algorithms.TreeLayoutObserver.TreeNode.isAncestorOf(TreeNode descendant)

I'm going to fix the problem because I can't wait for an official bug fix.